# Teradata Viewpoint Alerts and BTEQ

Tags: sql, teradata

Is there any way to pass a Viewpoint Alert Property (in this particular case ${SessionNo}) to a BTEQ script? 
I'm using 13.10 version and the Notification Service (which can execute a bteq script and pass it the TDPID, but i don't know nothing about the other properties)

Comment: I would suggest that this question is more appropriate for Database Administrators Stack Exchange than Stack Overflow. This question is more DBA specific than general database development related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a KSH script that calls BTEQ as an inline script.

Your script will need to be copied to Viewpoint Linux server at: `/opt/teradata/client/
cam/tdnotification/usrcmd/`

Then when you configure the Alert Action Set in Viewpoint instead of selecting the checkmark next to BTEQ select Run A Program. Choose the environment and program from the two dropdown boxes. There will a text box where you can define arguments such as SessionNo that you can refer to in your script.

`-SessionNo ${SessionNo} -db ${databaseName}`

Since the BTEQ script is embedded in the KSH the variable substitution should work without any problems.